# How to make Discord.js reply to discord DM messages

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get discord.js to read DM messages on Discord to have a bot that will be a server/faction application bot made from scratch but I Have it to send the first part when you type %apply to the bot the problem comes when trying to get passed question 2 it keeps getting question 2 instead of going to question 3

I am trying to filter out the DM messages when they are not the same as the passed ones so I have several if commands

````
bot.on("message", function(message) {
if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
    if (message.content === "%apply") {
        apply = "TRUE";
        a0 = message.author.lastMessageID
        message.author.sendMessage("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
        message.author.sendMessage("```Application Started - Type '#Cancel' to cancel the application```");
        message.author.sendMessage("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");
    }
    if ((message.guild === null) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a0) && (message.content != "%apply") && (apply === "TRUE")) {
        a1 = message.author.lastMessageID;
        message.author.sendMessage("```Question 2: Age?```");
    }
    if ((message.guild === null) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a1) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a0) && (apply === "TRUE")) {
        a2 = message.author.lastMessageID;
        message.author.sendMessage("```Question 3: Timezone? NA, AU, EU, NZ, or Other? (If other, describe your timezone)```");
    }
    if ((message.guild === null) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a2) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a1) && (message.author.lastMessageID != a0) && (apply === "TRUE")) {
        a3 = message.author.lastMessageID;
        message.author.sendMessage("```Question 4: Do you have schematica?```");
    }
````

I expected it to go from question 1 to question 2 the question 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Preface

Although [@Gruntzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393195/gruntzy)'s answer is not wrong, there's another solution that's built into Discord.js and meant for these situations - [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). You can use it in a system like shown below.

#### Sample Code

```js
const questions = [                    // ------------------------------------
  "What's your IGN?",                  //
  "How old are you?",                  // Define the questions you'd like the
  "What time zone do you reside in?",  // application to have in this array.
  "Do you have Schematica?"            //
];                                     // ------------------------------------

const applying = [];

bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "%apply") {
    if (applying.includes(message.author.id)) return;

    try {
      console.log(`${message.author.tag} began applying.`);

      applying.push(message.author.id);
      await message.channel.send(":pencil: **Application started!** Type `#cancel` to exit.");

      for (let i = 0, cancel = false; i < questions.length && cancel === false; i++) {
        await message.channel.send(questions[i]);
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"] })
          .then(collected => {
            if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === "#cancel") {
              await message.channel.send(":x: **Application cancelled.**");
              applying.splice(applying.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
              cancel = true;

              console.log(`${message.author.tag} cancelled their application.`);
            }
          }).catch(() => {
            await message.channel.send(":hourglass: **Application timed out.**");
            applying.splice(applying.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
            cancel = true;

            console.log(`${message.author.tag} let their application time out.`);
          });
      }

      await message.channel.send(":thumbsup: **You're all done!**");

      console.log(`${message.author.tag} finished applying.`);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Explanation

To make the code easier to understand, let's go through it step by step...

**1. Preceding lines.**

- The `questions` array contains all the questions you'd like to be asked in the application. I've implemented an array for the sake of efficiency; a question can be added or removed by changing only one line, and the same code won't be copied and pasted over and over again.
- The `applying` array will help us keep track of the users in the application process.

**2. Message event.**

- I've implemented an arrow function (ES6) as the callback and declared it async so we can use `await` inside of it.
- We prevent bots from triggering any commands.
- We check case iNsEnSiTiVeLy whether or not we should run the command.
- You'll notice that the proceeding code is wrapped in a [`try...catch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). This allows us to catch any [unhandled promise rejections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) (i.e. if [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) throws an error) easily.

**3. `%apply` command.**

- We add the user to the `applying` array.
- We send the start message.

  - Notice the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await): it waits for the promise to be fulfilled before moving on.
- We use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop to iterate through the `questions` array.

  - `let i = 0, cancel = false` declares `i` (the "counter" variable) and a `cancel` variable so we can stop the loop if the user wants to cancel the application or if it times out. We can't use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) within our [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback, so I've reverted to this method.
  - `i < questions.length && cancel === false` are our conditions to match before continuing with the next iteration - the counter must be within the range of the array, and `cancel` must still be `false`.
  - `i++` increments the counter by 1.
- Inside the loop, we send the question and then invoke [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). Our first parameter is a filter that the message must pass through, and the second is the options.

  - In our [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback, we check if the message was `#cancel`. If so, we send the cancellation message, remove the user from the array, and set `cancel`'s value to `true`.
  - Our [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method would be called if no message was provided in 5 minutes. So in our callback, we send the time out message, remove the user from the array, and set `cancel`'s value to `true`.
- Once the loop is complete, we send the completion message. At this point, you'd handle the application however you wish.

Comment: I understand the code but I want to save the answers to json when I call applying it only has the author.id but I want to get entire application how can I get that?

Comment: Thanks for this answer @slothiful. I didn't know about the `channel.awaitMessage` method, this is a really nice feature !

Comment: @Lonster_Monster Sorry for the late response. You could define an object in the command (`const application = {}`) and then inside the `for` loop and within your `then()` callback, enter each response into it (`application[questions[i]] = collected.first().content`). After the loop, you can insert that object into your json file like usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `a0, ... , a3` are inside the `"onMessage"` scope, and are undefined everytime in your callback. So if you message is not `%apply`, you are stuck into the "Question 2" step

You should keep track of your users registration steps in a global variable, and read it to know what step you are into. 
Here is a short example of how to do this.
Note that this is a really basic approach, and it might be better to use some in-memory database if you need to add more complex features to your apply procedure.
It also requires more controls, and I guess some other data storage to keep track of the user answers.

````
let userApplications = {}

bot.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

  let authorId = message.author.id;

  if (message.content === "%apply") {
      console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`);
      // User is not already in a registration process    
      if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
          userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

          message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
          message.author.send("```Application Started - Type '#Cancel' to cancel the application```");
          message.author.send("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");
      }

  } else {

      if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
          let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

          if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
              message.author.send("```Question 2: Age?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
              message.author.send("```Question 3: Timezone? NA, AU, EU, NZ, or Other? (If other, describe your timezone)```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
              message.author.send("```Question 4: Do you have schematica?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }

          else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
              message.author.send("```Thanks for your registration. Type %apply to register again```");
              delete userApplications[authorId];
          }

      }
  }


});
````

some other quick notes :

- `sendMessage(msg)` is deprecated in the discord.js api, `send(msg)` should be used now
- to test if the message received is a dm, i think it's better to check `message.channel.type` rather than looking for a empty `message.guildId`